# Is there a way to change macOS Terminal's theme/profile based on the system dark/light mode?

Tags: macos, themes, terminal.app

In macOS's Terminal app, the default theme (Basic) adapts dynamically to system settings, but as soon as I customize the Basic theme from the preferences menu, it stops adapting. Is there a way to manually configure Terminal to look at the system mode and choose a theme appropriately?

Comment: You mention a preference menu; don't confuse the *terminal*'s color scheme with anything provided by the shell.

Comment: What is the difference and what is the way to get the desired result?

Comment: The difference is, shells don't know anything about colors; they only output escape sequences that terminals *interpret* as requests display characters in a particular color, rather than displaying them directly.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

macOS's Terminal app doesn't have a setting to dynamically pick a theme. However, when customizing a theme (or creating your own), you can pick colors that dynamically adapt to the OS.

When choosing colors, go to the third tab and, from the drop-down at the top, choose Developer. These colors will adapt automatically to the current system theme.

⚠️ Caveat: If you modify these colors in any way (even only their opacity), they will stop adapting to the system theme.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Per the original question this does not select a them based on the Dark/Light mode of the system. This allows you to make a theme based on a color palette that changes with Dark.Light mode.

Comment: @JimmyBosse My answer solves the OP’s problem as posted: “ On ZSH the default theme (Basic) adapts dynamically to system settings, but as soon as I customise the Basic theme from the preferences menu it stops adapting.”

Comment:  I guess their question had two parts and we both saw it from different angles. My brain focused on the part, “Is there a way to manually configure ZSH to look at system mode and choose theme appropriately,” because that’s the question I had that landed me here. I tried to switch my downvote to an upvote but SO won’t let me. 

Comment: @JimmyBosse I edited the text. You should be able to change your vote now. 

Comment: The dynamic colours stop working as soon as you add transparency it seems.

Comment: Yeah, you cannot modify them in any way.

Comment: I updated my answer to mention this.

Answer (score 14):

For those who end up here looking for a way to change the terminal theme if your system is in Dark Mode, I did find this solution [dark-mode-macos-safari-iterm-vim](https://apas.gr/2018/11/dark-mode-macos-safari-iterm-vim/), you can default to a light theme and this will override with a dark theme when you launch Terminal in dark mode.

```sh
# Switch to Solarized Dark if we are currently in dark mode
if [[ "$(uname -s)" == "Darwin" ]]; then
  val=$(defaults read -g AppleInterfaceStyle 2>/dev/null)
  if [[ $val == "Dark" ]]; then
    osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"
      set current settings of tabs of windows to settings set "Solarized Dark" # Theme name
    end tell'
  else
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 7):

i created [auto-terminal-profile](https://github.com/ptrkcsk/auto-terminal-profile) to solve this problem

[image: screen recording of terminal changing profiles based on the macOS system appearance]

Comment: Works. Initially, nothing; because it takes just a little setup. After I ran most of the commands and MacOS prompted me to allow Terminal to make changes, then the app started working automatically (as in the visual). Thanks @ptrkcsk.